# How to find average score for each movie based on reviews - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, recommendation-engine

I have dataframe like this.

```
    UserID  Review      MovieID
0   10112   Good        MOV001
1   10112   Excellent   MOV002
2   10112   Average     MOV003
3   10113   Good        MOV001
4   10113   Bad         MOV002
5   10113   Good        MOV003
6   10113   Excellent   MOV004
7   10114   Good        MOV001
8   10114   Bad         MOV002
9   10114   Good        MOV003
10  10114   Excellent   MOV004
```

I've changed the reviews to int values.

```
movies.Review[movies.Status == 'Average'] = 2
movies.Review[movies.Status == 'Good'] = 3
movies.Review[movies.Status == 'Excellent'] = 5
movies.Review[movies.Status == 'Very Good'] = 4
movies.Review[movies.Status == 'Okay'] = 1
movies.Review[movies.Status == 'Bad'] = 0
movies
```

Now my dataframe will look like this,

```
UserID  Review      MovieID
0   10112   3           MOV001
1   10112   5           MOV002
2   10112   2           MOV003
3   10113   3           MOV001
4   10113   0           MOV002
5   10113   3           MOV003
6   10113   5           MOV004
7   10114   3           MOV001
8   10114   0           MOV002
9   10114   3           MOV003
10  10114   5           MOV004
```

Now how can I find the average score for each movie based on Review? Can anyone help me out?

Comment: `groupby.mean`??

Comment: Can you help me with the code?

Comment: As per your logic on setting the scores, look into `np.select`

Comment: Yes, as mentioned you need [`groupby.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html)

Comment: something like `movies.groupby('MovieID').mean()`

Comment: This also calculated mean for UserID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you don't need those `movies.Review[movies.Status==...] = ...`. Instead, use `np.select` or `map`:

```
Status_convert = {'Bad':0, 'Okay':1, 'Average':2,
                   'Good':3, 'Very Good':4, 'Excellent':5}
movies['Review'] = movies.Status.map(Status_convert)
```

Then you can do:

```
df.groupby('MovieID')['Review'].mean()
```

Output:

```
MovieID
MOV001    3.000000
MOV002    1.666667
MOV003    2.666667
MOV004    5.000000
Name: Review, dtype: float64
```